# SQL calculating percentages based on other alias'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the percentage of each type of task, green/amber/red, and output these values as a percentage in another column. The value of these columns, however, is only outputting as 0 or 1, not the true percentage. I cannot figure out why this is seeing as my other columns are outputting the correct values. where is my logic incorrect?

```
SELECT ValCat.ArgoBU as BusinessUnit, Validations.KpiMetrics, validations.MonthClose, 
   sum(1) as totTasks, 
   sum(iif(colour='Green',1,0)) as isGreen, 
   sum(iif(colour='Amber',1,0)) as isAmber, 
   sum(iif(colour='Red',1,0)) as isRed, 

--calculate percent of green/amber/red and display in separate column
--this is where its outputting 0/1, not desired percentage
   format((sum(iif(colour='Green',1,0))/sum(1)), 'P') as PercGreen, 
   format((sum(iif(colour='Amber',1,0))/sum(1)), 'P') as PercAmber, 
   format((sum(iif(colour='Red',1,0))/sum(1)), 'P') as PercRed
FROM validations 
INNER JOIN valcat on validations.BusinessUnit = ValCat.BusinessUnit 
GROUP BY ArgoBU, KpiMetrics, MonthClose
```

For example, line 1 shows totTasks: 1651, isGreen: 983, but PercGreen displays 0 rather than 59.5%. I cannot figure out why this is as the code for these columns is the exact same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using sum(1.0) or cast it to decimal in your Percentage calculation. If both are integers the result will be an integer and for that reason  you see 0/1.

Ex:

```
SELECT format((sum(iif(color='GREEN',1,0))/sum(1.0)), 'P') PercGreen,--updated
, (sum(iif(color='GREEN',1,0))/sum(1)) GreenDivInt --original
FROM
(
    SELECT 'GREEN' AS COLOR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GREEN' AS COLOR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GREEN' AS COLOR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GREEN' AS COLOR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GREEN' AS COLOR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GREEN' AS COLOR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GREEN1' AS COLOR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GREEN1' AS COLOR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GREEN1' AS COLOR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GREEN1' AS COLOR
) S
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you so much, I learn something new about SQL every day.